# WooCommerce: woocommerce_login_redirect filter custom redirect if username/password not correct

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

After doing several tests I noticed that the `woocommerce_login_redirect` filter only runs if the login details are correct.

Is there a way to append to the URL when it redirects after a bad sign-in? All I really want to achieve is to make it scroll to the form i.e. http://example.com/#signin

Thank you very much for any advice.

**edit:**

I've managed to find a hacky way around it but was really hoping if anyone knows how to achieve it properly. Here is what I've done to make it work:

`<form action="#members" method="post" class="login">`

On successful login, however, it retains the fragment so the URL comes out as something like this: http://example.com/my-account/#members... not something desirable but not a huge headache either if there isn't a proper way in achieving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a hacky way around it but was really hoping if anyone knows how to achieve it properly. Here is what I've done to make it work:

On successful login, however, it retains the fragment so the URL comes out as something like this: http://example.com/my-account/#members... not something desirable but not a huge headache either if there isn't a proper way in achieving it.